# Entity Framework Core 6 is creating Shadow Key instead of using defined foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core Version 6.0.9 to connect to a database to export my data. Because of that I used database first approach and autogenerated my model with help of the Entity Framework. I load my tables with eager loading. Most things work correctly, but I can't include one table (`BeschaeftigungsAddendum`), because it's throwing an error:

> Invalid column name 'BeschaeftigungBid'

I assume, that at this point Entity Framework creates a shadow key, because I never defined an attribute `BeschaeftigungsBid`, nor is something like that in the database.

My problem is, that I defined, as written in the documentation and many other threads, a foreign key. But it seems like the Entity Framework is still creating a shadow key.

Building the entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BeschaeftigungsAddendum>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Baid);

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Beschaeftigung, e.Addendum }, "IX_BeschaeftigungsAddendum")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Baid).HasColumnName("BAID");

            entity.Property(e => e.Addendum)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(64)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Expires)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("('9999-12-31T23:59:59')");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdate)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .IsFixedLength();

            entity.Property(e => e.Lastversion)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsRowVersion()
                .IsConcurrencyToken()
                .HasColumnName("lastversion");

            entity.Property(e => e.Wert)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(256);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.BeschaeftigungNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.BeschaeftigungsAddendum)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Beschaeftigung)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_BeschaeftigungsAddendum_Beschaeftigung");
                            
        });
```

Entity Build Beschaeftigung:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Beschaeftigung>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Bid);

            entity.HasComment("Nachweis der Beschaeftigungsverhaeltnisse");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.Mitarbeiter, e.Beginn, e.KostenStelle, e.DatenQuelle }, "IX_Beschaeftigung")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Bid)
                .HasColumnName("BID")
                .HasComment("Schluessel");

            entity.Property(e => e.Beginn)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasComment("Beschaeftigungsbeginn (W3CDTF)");

            entity.Property(e => e.DienstBezeichnung).HasComment("Verweis nach Dienstbezeichnung");

            entity.Property(e => e.Einrichtung).HasComment("Verweis nach Diensstelle");

            entity.Property(e => e.Ende)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasComment("Beschaeftigugsende (W3CDTF)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Expires)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("('9999-12-31T23:59:59')");

            entity.Property(e => e.KostenStelle)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(10)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasComment("Verweis nach Diensstelle");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdate)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasComment("Zeitstempel (W3CDTF)")
                .UseCollation("Latin1_General_CI_AS");

            entity.Property(e => e.Lastversion)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsRowVersion()
                .IsConcurrencyToken()
                .HasColumnName("lastversion")
                .HasComment("wegen Concurrency");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updater).HasComment("Verweis nach Person");

            entity.Property(e => e.Wd).HasColumnName("WD");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.DatenQuelleNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Beschaeftigung)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DatenQuelle)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Beschaeftigung_DatenQuelle");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.DienstBezeichnungNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Beschaeftigung)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DienstBezeichnung)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Beschaeftigung_Dienstbezeichnung");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.EinrichtungNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Beschaeftigung)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Einrichtung)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Beschaeftigung_Einrichtung");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.MitarbeiterNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Beschaeftigung)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Mitarbeiter)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Beschaeftigung_Mitarbeiter");
        });
```

Model class `Beschaeftigung` (employment):

```
public partial class Beschaeftigung
{
    public Beschaeftigung()
    {
        BeschaeftigungsAddendum = new HashSet<BeschaeftigungsAddendum>();
        BueroAnschrift = new HashSet<BueroAnschrift>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Schluessel
    /// </summary>
    public int Bid { get; set; }
    public int Mitarbeiter { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Beschaeftigungsbeginn (W3CDTF)
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Beginn { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Beschaeftigugsende (W3CDTF)
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Ende { get; set; }
    public bool Wd { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Verweis nach Dienstbezeichnung
    /// </summary>
    public int? DienstBezeichnung { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Verweis nach Diensstelle
    /// </summary>
    public int Einrichtung { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Verweis nach Diensstelle
    /// </summary>
    public string KostenStelle { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Verweis nach Person
    /// </summary>
    public int Updater { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Zeitstempel (W3CDTF)
    /// </summary>
    public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// wegen Concurrency
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] Lastversion { get; set; }
    public int DatenQuelle { get; set; }

    public virtual DatenQuelle DatenQuelleNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Dienstbezeichnung DienstBezeichnungNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Einrichtung EinrichtungNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Mitarbeiter MitarbeiterNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BeschaeftigungsAddendum> BeschaeftigungsAddendum { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BueroAnschrift> BueroAnschrift { get; set; }
}
```

The model class `BeschaeftigungsAddendum`:

```
public partial class BeschaeftigungsAddendum
{
    public int Baid { get; set; }
    public int Beschaeftigung { get; set; }
    public string Addendum { get; set; }
    public string Wert { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public int Updater { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Lastversion { get; set; }

    public virtual Beschaeftigung BeschaeftigungNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

I load the context like this:

```
using (var kommDBContext = new kommdbContext(kommDBConnection))
{
    queryContext = kommDBContext.Person; 
    queryContext = queryContext
                        .Include(p => p.Mitarbeiter)
                        .ThenInclude(m => m.Beschaeftigung)
                        .ThenInclude(b => b.BeschaeftigungsAddendum);
    var sql = queryContext.ToQueryString();

    result = queryContext.ToList();
}
```

What I tried so far:

- I tried to rename `BeschaeftigungsAddendum.Beschaeftigung`
- I tried to add explicit in the `BeschaeftigungsAddendum` class a foreign key.
- I tried to add an attribute `BescaheftigungsBid` and not map it. But most of those solutions, just lead to a different name of the automatic generated shadow key, but Entity Framework still creates a shadow key that can't be found.

I also tried to recreate all of the model

I can't understand why this attribute is automatically added in the SQL query, even though correct keys are defined.

The relevant part of the query is

```
SELECT [b].[BID], [b].[Beginn], [b].[DatenQuelle], [b].[DienstBezeichnung], [b].[Einrichtung], [b].[Ende], [b].[Expires], [b].[KostenStelle], [b].[LastUpdate], [b].[lastversion], [b].[Mitarbeiter], [b].[Updater], [b].[WD], [b0].[BAID], [b0].[Addendum], [b0].[Beschaeftigung], [b0].[BeschaeftigungBid], [b0].[Expires] AS [Expires0], [b0].[LastUpdate] AS [LastUpdate0], [b0].[lastversion] AS [lastversion0], [b0].[Updater] AS [Updater0], [b0].[Wert]
FROM [Beschaeftigung] AS [b]
LEFT JOIN [BeschaeftigungsAddendum] AS [b0] ON [b].[BID] = [b0].[Beschaeftigung]
```

[b0].[BeschaeftigungBid] is nowhere defined.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Are any character in the column Unicode characters?

Comment: Thanks for reply. This column is an integer column: Beschaeftigung(FK,int,not null)

Comment: It is the name of the column that is an issue, not the numeric value.

Comment: All columns are named only with asci characters, no special characters are in there: BAID, Beschaeftigung, Addendum, Wert, Expires, Updater, LastUpdate, lastversion

Comment: Please include in the question the fluent configuration of the `Beschaeftigung` entity. "Phantom" FK columns usually are coming from misconfigured relationships (the one you posted looks ok though) and/or duplicate conflicting relationship configuration, which probably is the case here. For instance, having `entity.HasMany(p => p.BeschaeftigungsAddendum).WithOne();` in the configuration I'm asking for.

Comment: I included the fluent configuration Beschaeftigung

Comment: Thanks, but with the model and configuration you've posted (after commenting out the non compiling properties) the issue does not reproduce in a clean new project, so something seems to be missing. Can you reproduce it in a clean (console) project with just the two entities and fluent config from question?

Comment: Error says : Invalid column name 'BeschaeftigungBid'.  Where is that name in Entiry? Did you open EDMX mapping file with Notepad to check name?

Comment: I couldn't find any hint in the EDMX File. But I created a new Project and created the model new with EF Core Power Tools. In this clean Project everything worked fine. Luckily I use the Entity Framework Project only as reference for my Export Project, so there was not that much code to rewrite. So creating a clean Project solved my Problem, but I can't exactly say, why this is the case. I thank you all for your help and for your time